# Automatically refreshing cache on a IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server

Sorry for the lack of knowledge here guys by the agency I work for has inherited a site built on windows server with ASP.net.

We're having problems with the user login system. The basic story is when a user requests an account an admin must approve it. If the admin rejects the user application the user can then still login by using the forgot password option.

My initial reaction is bad logic in the code but we've had some ASP guys take a quick look and were unable to reproduce the problem. Because of this they've suggested it might be some kind of caching issue. If so is there anyway to set the sever to reset it's cache every hour or so? or any other recommendations on this are also welcome.  Sorry for the complete lack of code examples but a scenario is all I can offer right now.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't reproduce it then there is no problem; although I concede there might be a caching problem. But without knowing more about your application all I can suggest is to grep your source code for references to the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` class (usually accessed via the `Page` class directly if not by `HttpContext.Current`).

Removing the idea of a cache being responsible, I think it's just a case of bad coding of the forgot-password feature. I guess is the forgot-password feature resets some kind of "account disabled" flag and that's what allows the user to get in.

Comment: Don't forget System.Runtime.Caching! - It came along somewhat recently, but if you are suggesting a text search he should probably look for both.

Answer (score 1):

The [ASP.Net caching class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) has an iterator for the cached items, and a method to remove an item.  It's difficult to host long-running processes in IIS -- because "idle" worker processes get killed -- so you can't just run a timer.  But you can use the [IIS auto-start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) feature, combined with a persistent store, to run your "nuke the cache" method every hour.

With that said, I can't see how this is a sensible solution to the problem -- I hope the plan here is just to help isolate the real issue.